# Can we use click() functionality along with sendKeys()?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can we use Click() functionality along with sendKeys()?? 
I just read a drop-down value using xpath and now i need to click on the particular value i have read. Actually its possible to use in two steps. But is there any option to read and click in a single code??

Thanks,
SK

Comment: You should look at "Actions" class... In Java -
 https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html.

Comment: Thanks for the information

Comment: Can you give us the code that you have tried?

Comment: @santhoshkumar driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("Talk-Talk");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click(); Here you can see i have written those codes in two lines.

Comment: Can you try this? driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("Talk-Talk",Keys.ENTER);

Comment: @santhoshkumar Let me check

Comment: @santhoshkumar Yeah It's working... Thank You so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly try with this. I have used Enter key as a substitute for clicking.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("Talk-Talk",K‌​eys.ENTER);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to select some specific option in dropdown then use select class.

Go though [this article](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-select-methods-to-work-with-dropdowns) for more info

But if you want to click on some element and then send some text, then you can user Action class.

```
WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(wb).click().moveToElement(wb,200, 0).sendkeys("text").build().perform();//you need to specify where you need to send text 200,0 is just as an example
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. Let me check.

Comment: What is the requirement of adding an offset in moveToElement method for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

WebElement MobileNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourxpath"));
action.moveToElement(MobileNumber).click().sendKeys("your text").build().perform();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any difference with this answer?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46883073/5468463

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.

Yes you can if you use `.then()` function.

No if you try inline function `.click().sendKeys('1+1=3')` (Not Work)

You can do like this:

```js
await $browser.waitForAndFindElement($driver.By.id('element_id'))
    .then(async (e) => {
        await e.click();
        await e.sendKeys('1+1=3');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [**`Java Docs`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html), `click()` method returns `void` as follows:

```
void click()
```

Similarly, `sendKeys()` method also returns `void` as follows :

```
void sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)
```

So as per best programming practice we must not try to club-up **`click()`** method with **`sendKeys()`** method or vice versa. It would be ideal to achieve the intended task in two separate steps.

Comment: You are referring to the methods in WebElement interface. But you can build the commands using the Actions class in which these methods return Actions.